# Rotating a circle on mouse click by particular angle using transitionTo of kineticJs

Tags: html, kineticjs, html5-animation

I have a circle with 4 sectors. On clicking sector 1 and 3, circle should rotate by a particular angle, say 45degrees in clockwise direction and on clicking sector 2 and 4, circle should rotate in anti clockwise direction by the same angle. How to do it using transitionTo method of kineticJS?

I am using

```
    sector1.on("click", function() {
    circle.transitionTo({
                rotation: Math.PI/4,
                duration: 1

            });
     });

    sector2.on("click", function() {
    circle.transitionTo({
                rotation: -Math.PI/4,
                duration: 1

            });
     });
```

but the transition does not seem to work after the first click. Can any one tell the reason for the inconsistent rotation...do i need to save the context of the kinetic layer afer each rotation???

Answer (score 0):

The reason it only seems to work for the first click is that you're telling the circle to rotate **to** a specific angle.  You need to tell it to rotate to a new angle each time, by adding Math.PI/4 to the current angle:

```
circle.transitionTo({
            rotation: circle.getRotation() + Math.PI/4,
            duration: 1
        });
 });
```

Here's a jsfiddle with a small demonstration showing the difference: http://jsfiddle.net/johnwiseman/WuZNg/